# ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() encountering FileNotFoundException when trying to update URI

Tags: java, android, activityresultcontracts

I'm new to Android and Java.  I'm trying to take a photo from the camera, and update an imageview with the result.  I'm struggling and could use some points in the right direction.

I've set up an empty Uri variable:

`Uri cameraOneUri = Uri.EMPTY;`

My button click calls this function:

```
public void captureImage1(View view){
        c1GetContent.launch(cameraOneUri);
    }
```

And here's the registration:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> c1GetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
            result -> {
                ImageView imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView1.setImageURI(cameraOneUri);
    });
```

But I'm getting a FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1846)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1562)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1537)
        at com.android.camera.captureintent.state.StateSavingPicture.onEnter(StateSavingPicture.java:85)
        at com.android.camera.captureintent.stateful.StateMachineImpl.jumpToState(StateMachineImpl.java:62)
        at com.android.camera.captureintent.stateful.StateMachineImpl.processEvent(StateMachineImpl.java:110)
        at com.android.camera.captureintent.state.StateOpeningCamera$9.onClick(StateOpeningCamera.java:307)
```

Where should I begin to look?

Comment: The value that you supply to `launch()` needs to be a `Uri` where you want the image to be written. `Uri.EMPTY` is not a valid location. Use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` where you want to save the image.

Comment: Ah OK, I was trying to treat it like any other variable.  I'll read up on `FileProvider` thank you very much.